# control file to PHP array

Tags: php, deb

In Linux, .DEB files have 'control' text files that are arranged as follows:

```
Name: Value
Size: Value
Information: Mutliline
             value
```

What is the best way to get the control file into a PHP array resembling:

```
Array ( "Name" => Value, "Size" => Value, "Information" => Value);
```

keeping in mind that the values can be multi-line and include the ":" separator.

Thanks!

Comment: Too bad it seems to be a proprietary format and not something like YAML, at least not according to this http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html

Comment: From my (limited) work packaging .debs, I think it follows the same syntax as HTTP headers... maybe there is a PHP library that can parse those?

Comment: @Pekka: come again?  It is basic RFC822 format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$source = fopen('path/to/file');
$index = '';
while( ($line = fgets($source)) !== false ){
    if(preg_match('/^\s*$/', $line))
        continue 1; // ignore empty lines //

    if(!preg_match('/^\s+/', $line)){ // if the line does not start with whitespace then it has a new key-value pair //
        $items = explode(':', $line, 2); // separate at the first : //
        $index = strtolower($items[0]); // the keys are case insensitive //
        $value = preg_replace('/^\s+/', '', $items[1]); // remove extra whitespace from the begining //
        $value = preg_replace('/\s+$/', '', $value); // and from the end //
    }
    else{ // continue the value from the previous line //
        $value = preg_replace('/\s+$/', '', $line); // remove whitespace only from the end //
    }
    $data[$index] .= $value;
}
fclose($source);
```

Implemented as described here: http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html

If I made mistakes corrections are welcomed!

Comment: Tested with a range of control files and it seems to be working nicely! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

//image attribute is the name attribute in the Input File Field just as name that used for the Post Methode

```
// return array of errros
public function Controle_upload_file($file_field_name,$max_photo_uploading_size=10485760,$allow_exts=["JPG","GIF","PNG","JPEG"],$request_type="POST"){
    //fix bytes shows
    $errors=array();
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == $request_type && isset($_FILES[$file_field_name])){
        $name=$_FILES[$file_field_name]["name"];
        $size=$_FILES[$file_field_name]["size"];
        $type_file=explode("/",$_FILES[$file_field_name]["type"]);
        $type=strtoupper(end($type_file));
        $tmp_name=$_FILES[$file_field_name]["tmp_name"];
        //check if user choosed a photo
        if(empty($size)){$errors[]="You Must Choose A Photo ";}
        else{
            if(! in_array($type,$allow_exts)){$errors[]="Invalid File Format Must Be ".implode(",",$allow_exts);}
            if($size>$max_photo_uploading_size){$errors[]="Too Large File the Size Must be under ". $max_photo_uploading_size." Bytes";} 
}//end else 
    }else{$errors[]="Somthing Went Wrong";}
    return $errors;
//end function
}
$errors=$function->Controle_upload_file("image"); //image attribute is the name attribute in the Input File Field just as name that used for the Post Methode
```